# Maximum number of PEP8 violations in a single line

Tags: code-challenge, python

Your task is to write a file which contains a line with many [pep8 violations](http://pep8.readthedocs.org/en/latest/intro.html#error-codes).

**The rules:**

- We use pep8 version 1.5.7 and the default settings.
- Calling pep8 with other command line options or using a custom rc file is not allowed.
- Maximum line length 120 characters.  You can violate E501, sure, but the line which your score is calculated on has to be <= 120 characters.
- Your module can have other lines before or after, but only one line contributes to your score.
- Your file can contain SyntaxErrors or any kind of garbage, it needn't import or run.

**Example of scoring:**

The following module `thing.py` has a score of 2, because it contains a line (line 1) with 2 pep8 violations.

```
 spam='potato'
```

**To check a score:**

```
~$ mktmpenv 
(tmp-ae3045bd2f629a8c)~/.virtualenvs/tmp-ae3045bd2f629a8c$ pip install pep8==1.5.7
(tmp-ae3045bd2f629a8c)~/.virtualenvs/tmp-ae3045bd2f629a8c$ echo -n "spam='potato'" > thing.py
(tmp-ae3045bd2f629a8c)~/.virtualenvs/tmp-ae3045bd2f629a8c$ pep8 thing.py 
thing.py:1:5: E225 missing whitespace around operator
thing.py:1:14: W292 no newline at end of file
```

Comment: Is this a... language-specific challenge? Because we don't really like these.

Comment: I guess it's not really language specific (because the file can contain any garbage) but obviously people familiar with python coding will have some advantage

Answer (score 11):

## 241

if you want the most error, just go crazy with semicolon

```
$ cat test.py
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

$ cat test.py | wc -m
120

$ pep8 test.py | wc -l
241
```

most of the error are:

```
test.py:1:119: E231 missing whitespace after ';'
test.py:1:119: E702 multiple statements on one line (semicolon)
```

with those error at the end:

```
test.py:1:120: E703 statement ends with a semicolon
test.py:1:121: W292 no newline at end of file
```

Comment: @wim couldn't reply to your post so i just put it here. you were right about the advantage, i be surprise if someone figure out something else that cause more error then what i posted above

Comment: I think you are a semicolon short. wc counts the trailing newline, but we don't count that for character counts on this site. As you can see in your code quote, your last character is #119. You should get 240, 2 for each semicolon except the last one, 1 for the overly long line, and 1 for ending with a semicolon.

Comment: @isaacg ah, you are right, i thought it was weird that it gotten less error than number of character * 2, i blame gedit for adding the invisible newline :P

Comment: haha, kind of cheap .. but effective!  +1

Answer (score 7):

## 123

Yes, more violations than characters!

```
$ curl -s http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=RwLJfa0Q | cat
 (  =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =   =
$ curl -s http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=RwLJfa0Q | wc -m
 120
$ curl -s http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=RwLJfa0Q | pep8 - | wc -l
 123
```

The trick is that an `=` after a `(` makes pep think you're doing a keyword in a function call (e.g. `foo(bar=12)`). In this context, doing `[TAB]=` triggers both

```
killpep.py:1:3: E223 tab before operator
killpep.py:1:3: E251 unexpected spaces around keyword / parameter equals
```

And doing `=[TAB]` triggers both

```
killpep.py:1:5: E224 tab after operator
killpep.py:1:5: E251 unexpected spaces around keyword / parameter equals
```

Gleefully enough, you can just chain these.

This gives a violation count of one per character. I need `(` to set it up, but not providing the `)` gives us:

```
killpep.py:2:1: E901 TokenError: EOF in multi-line statement
```

That's 120. No newline = 121. It managed to trigger the "line too long" error, so that's 122. Finally, using one character to start with a space (thanks [eric_lagergren](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/34581/maximum-number-of-pep8-violations-in-a-single-line/34595#comment74154_34595)) gives 2 violations instead of 1:

```
killpep.py:1:2: E111 indentation is not a multiple of four
killpep.py:1:2: E113 unexpected indentation
```

Victory!

Comment: Add a leading whitespace and remove the last `z` and you'll end up with 103... but whenever I copy this code I get 83 instead of 102. I think the spacing is getting messed up.

Comment: @eric_lagergren: I'm using tabs instead of spaces and I guess they aren't copying properly. Will pastebin it I guess!